# Disturbing film, made in last 5-7 years about a disabled mother and her son

Tags: identify-this-movie

I only watched probably the last 30 mins of this film. It had some incest between a mother and son. The son is disturbed finding his mother attractive. The mother breaks her leg and he has to look after her on his own as the father treats them badly and i am not sure if he beats them but he is around. He also try to strangle himself in the bathroom with his belt but the mother interrupts him.The son hangs about with his friends that take drugs and drink and he try to kill himself by jumping off a hill into a lake i think at the end, but that doesn't work. I am not sure if the actors in this. Its mainly about the boy and the mom.

Answer (score 5):

It could be [Spanking the Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanking_the_Monkey)

> Susan Aibelli, a married, lonely woman, suffers a leg injury at home just as her husband is about to leave on his job as a travelling salesman and her son, Raymond, is about to leave for the summer on a medical internship. Raymond is then forced to stay at home to take care of her as his father cannot. He loses both the internship and his girlfriend. These troublesome events leave him emotionally confused as he and his mother are left alone together, and they develop an incestuous relationship.

I have not watched it, so can't say if it's disturbing or not but it was listed as Black comedy.

Answer (score 2):

Most definitely SPANKING THE MONKEY. The lead character has an affair with his mom after she breaks her leg, and he attempts suicide afterward. 
It is a very dark, twisted comedy. From 1994, starring Jeremy Davies from Saving Private Ryan and Justified and directed by David O. Russell